# What's an efficient way to plot many features for EDA in python?

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to visualize data for exploratory data analysis motivated by visualizing  multiple scatterplots of features simultaneously, [similar to this question](http://What's%20the%20easiest%20way%20to%20quickly%20plot%20several%20features%20simultaneously%20for%20new%20data?). But I quickly run into problems when using a large number of features (~50) and rows (~50K). While I like using [seaborn pairplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) the generation of a large number of plot panes can get computational intractable for a large number of features and observations. Subsetting a very large table to a smaller number of features or observations does not seem complete.

My question is: What's an efficient way to plot many features for EDA in python? If there is not an efficient way then is there a defensible way to reduce the number of features or observations

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest t-SNE (just google it). It helps you to have a general overview on what is gling on with your high-dimensional data. Please note that parameters of t-SNE are pretty sensitive so you need to put some effort to find a good embedding.